# What is the best practice for storing gems for a project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I found my gem location using `gem env`, and it's outside the root of my project. I'm assuming I can change this location to a directory within my project, but is there a best practice for Gem locations? I'm asking because there are some patched Gems on Github I'd like to try, but I don't want to overwrite the originals in my original gem file, in case it messes with other projects.

Comment: BTW I'm using ruby 1.9.2p290 with RVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/), which makes it really easy to juggle different versions of gems (including gems installed from git) without different projects interfering with each other.

You could also use different gemsets, but I've never found that necessary with bundler

Answer (score 1):

You have `RVM`, Go for a different gemset if and only if you really need to install a version which is way ahead or past of the current version which would lead you to install different versions of lot of its dependencies. Beware of the dependencies.

Do not forget to check about the dependencies if you wish over [here.](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/)

If you do have dependencies built a new gemset by ::

`rvm gemset create name_of_gemset`

Once that's been done, you can always go to the folder your project is situated and make a particular gemset default.

`rvm gemset list`

and

`rvm default@gemset_name --default`

OR

`rvm default@gemset_name`